# How to open a FORM VIEW by using Server Actions?

Tags: view, odoo, odoo-12

Can I open a FORM VIEW via a button defined by using Server Actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Both action types "Execute Python Code" and "Execute Several Actions" should work this way. The second one only when the last "child" action will be of type "Execute Python Code".

You have to set `action` in the python code of an action, to open a form view.

In Odoo 12 there is already an example with app "account" installed. The ID of that action is `account.action_invoice_tree2` and the code looks like:

```py
action_values = env.ref('account.action_vendor_bill_template').read()[0]
new_help = model.complete_empty_list_help()
action_values.update({'help': action_values.get('help', '') + new_help})
action = action_values
```

So Odoo is expecting a dictionary like you probably already have used in your module's code. But instead of returning a dictionary, you have to set variable `action` in server actions.

You can not only open form views, but also tree, kanban and so on.